# Angular update from V8 to V13

Tags: angular, frontend, angular8, web-frontend, angular13

I am trying to update my application with Angular version 8 to the latest i.e. v13. I have read all required documents/procedures from the angular website https://update.angular.io/ and started upgrading the version.

As instructed I have upgraded the intermediate version step by step by following one higher version of the previous. for example, 8-9-10 likewise.
Now I am facing one major issue on serving server locally i.e. ng serve command. The rest of the dependencies and plugins version are fixed, and all are updated according to the latest version.

current environment: node 17, Angular CLI 13

```
Problem Statement:  Error: src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:168:14 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of LearnerComponentModule, but itself has errors
168 export class SharedModule {
```

I have one shared module which contains all modules related to plugins that are used commonly for other modules, so i'm using this module as a shared module. And thus this shared module is imported into other modules.
What am I missing here?

Comment: "but itself has errors" - can you check if see any other errors when building?

Comment: Can you share the code of both modules please